# How to check whether column value is NULL or having DEFAULT value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch records for column value not equal to null and column value not equal to default value.
I know that we can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name is NOT NULL AND column_name != 'some_default_value';
```

but what if some one in future changes this some_default_value in table?
Is there a flexible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DEFAULT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE IFNULL(column_name, DEFAULT(column_name)) <> DEFAULT(column_name);
```

Comment: Learnt 1 more function today.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rows.count it would help you know if the table is null or thus contain same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DEFAULT function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default) in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM grouptable WHERE column_name is NOT NULL and column_name <> DEFAULT( column_name )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **information_schema.COLUMNS** table to find the default values including all the definition of the table.

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `Matches` (
  `FootballerName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Goal` int(11) DEFAULT '5',
  `Tournament` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

**Raw Data for the Table**

```
insert into Matches(FootballerName,Goal,Tournament)
select 'Messi ', 3 ,'La liga' union
select 'Ronaldo ', 5 ,'UEFA' union
select 'Surez ', 2 ,'La liga';
```

**Required Query to achieve the required.**

```
SELECT * FROM Matches WHERE Goal not in(
select COLUMN_DEFAULT from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Matches' 
 and COLUMN_NAME='Goal');
```

You can read more about the **"information_schema.COLUMNS"** [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)